# SQL Server 2008 R2 Merge is deleteing the wrong set of data

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the table `tblCollectionGameList`

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblCollectionGameList
(
    ListID smallint IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    CollectionID smallint NOT NULL,
    IncludedSectionID smallint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CollectionGameList_ListID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ListID ASC),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CollectionGameList_SectionInfo FOREIGN KEY (CollectionID) REFERENCES dbo.tblSectionInfo (SectionID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CollectionGameList_SectionInfo2 FOREIGN KEY (IncludedSectionID) REFERENCES dbo.tblSectionInfo (SectionID)
)
```

which I run the following `MERGE` command on after passing an XML set of values to from my website

```
SELECT 
   CAST(colx.query('data(CollectionID) ') AS varchar) AS CollectionID,
   CAST(colx.query('data(IncludedSectionID) ') AS varchar) AS IncludedSectionID
INTO #TEMPtblCollectionGameList
FROM @XMLTable.nodes('DocumentElement/XMLTable') AS Tabx(Colx)

MERGE dbo.tblCollectionGameList AS t
USING #TEMPtblCollectionGameList AS s
ON (t.CollectionID = s.CollectionID AND t.IncludedSectionID= s.IncludedSectionID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT (CollectionID, IncludedSectionID)
        VALUES (s.CollectionID, s.IncludedSectionID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN
        DELETE
;
```

which is not working right. If I have an existing set of data in my table:

```
ListID  CollectionID    IncludedSectionID
34      86              0
35      86              1
```

and I try to place new data from my web page for a collection with a different `CollecitonID` it is removing the old data and placing the new data in:

```
ListID  CollectionID    IncludedSectionID
38      92              10
39      92              11
```

what is wrong with my `MERGE` code that is making it affect items outside the `CollectionID` that the webpage is passing for an update?

Comment: `when not matched by source` is deleting all rows in the target table that is not part of the source data.

Comment: What is the point of comparing the columns twice in the `on`clause? Did you mean to compare something else?

Comment: Corrected the on clause I copyed the code from a test script while I was trying to figure out it out on my own, the corrected is what I originaly had before testing. Could I through an if statment in the WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE section to check that CollectionID is the same as in the #TEMPtblCollectionGameList then delete or is there some other way to get the MERGE command to only affect the data withe the CollEctionID that is is listed in #TEMPtblCollectionGameList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the following:

```
WITH tblCGL AS
(
    SELECT ListID, CollectionID, IncludedSectionID
    FROM dbo.tblCollectionGameList AS CGL
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT CollectionID, IncludedSectionID
        FROM #TEMPtblCollectionGameList AS TempCGL
        WHERE CGL.CollectionID = TempCGL.CollectionID
    )
)
```

this was gather by the help at the guys from SQLteam.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to the `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` clause.

```
merge dbo.tblCollectionGameList as T
using #TEMPtblCollectionGameList as S
on S.CollectionID = T.CollectionID and
   S.IncludedSectionID = T.IncludedSectionID
when not matched by target
  then
    insert(CollectionID, IncludedSectionID)
      values(S.CollectionID, S.IncludedSectionID)
when not matched by source and 
     T.CollectionID in (select S.CollectionID
                        from #TEMPtblCollectionGameList as S)
  then
    delete
;
```

Comment: That causes the error:
The identifier 's.CollectionID' cannot be bound. Only target columns are allowed in the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE' clause of a MERGE statement.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete Sorry about that. I have updated my answer with [something that works](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82238).